# ViewController.Type does not have a member named view

Tags: swift

I have created a new project in Swift, and added a second ViewController to the storyboard, added a class file and linked it. Now I'm trying to access the view of the new vc in the initial vc:

```
let settingsView = SettingsViewController.view
```

But it returns the error:

```
SettingsViewController.Type does not have a member named view
```

Why is that? How can the view controller not have a view? The view is connected correctly to the VC in the Connections Inspector.

Comment: Show us the class definition of `SettingsViewController`.

Comment: It's just the default code for a class derived from UIViewController.

Comment: import UIKit

class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is, because you try to access `view` on the type itself, but not on the instance. That means you have to instantiate the view controller first and after that you can access its members, i.e. (pseudo-swift-code)

```
let settingsVc = SettingsViewController()
addNewVcToHierarchy(settingsVc)

let settingsView = settingsVc.view
```

However, usually you do not want to access the view directly from a view controller where it does not belongs to but instead push data into the view controller (e.g. on a segue).

Comment: Thank you! I have to find out more about the proper way of pushing data to the view controllers then.

Comment: Usually this is done in `prepareForSegue`, or you build the stack of view controllers in `AppDelegate` by yourself and directly assign their properties.